# fix div width @media fix for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media

I have a div set to 100% width, and when the page is being looked at 1024 resolution the width should change from 100% to 1000px, I got it working properly with @media queries and works fine on FF, safari chrome. But ie8 and below ignores it, is there any other to try to get the div to change the width from 100% to 1000px at 1024 resolution on IE?
I tried this with jquery but doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    $('#content')css('width','1000px')
} else {
    $('#content')css('width','100%')
};
}
```

Comment: Try `$(document).width();` instead of `$(window).width();`. Also you have a typo in calling `css` function - the dot is missing.

Comment: Oops I did thank Sven for his answer and used it, it was a honest mistake on my part forgetting to click on the check mark, I didn't noticed I had more answers either so to all thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

media queries are CSS3. Means not supported by IE8 and lower. But take a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/), that brings support for media queries to IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", changeWidth));

function changeWidth( e ) {
    if($(window).width()<1024)
    {
        $('#content').css('width','1000px');
    } else {
        $('#content').css('width','100%');
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WHdWE/)

Comment: Just be cautious in relying on the resize event, as it gets triggered in a lot of different cases, including phone orientation changes, and some browsers continually fire the resize event, which means a lot of manipulation can quickly bog down your browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
    $(window).resize(function () {
    var width = screen.width;
    var height = screen.height;
    if (width <= 1024) {
        //somecode
    } else {
        //somecode

    }
 });
```

however,as Sven Bieder mentioned CSS Media Queries are better than for Responsive Design.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set this in CSS:

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 1000px;
```

It's infinitely more efficient than any JS/jQuery solution, I can assure you.